# HAProxy health check, particularly in mode tcp

Tags: haproxy

I've looked at this previous question [HAProxy health check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512029/haproxy-health-check/23573472#23573472) and see that the HAProxy directives have changed significantly in this area. The "monitor" directive seems to be the modern way to do this.

I want to have a proxy running in tcp mode, that's capable of reporting its availability to clients.

I can have a separate listener in http mode, that gives a 200OK response:

```
frontend  main
    # See "bind" documentation at https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#4.2-bind
    #   The proxy will listen on all interfaces for connections to the specified port.
    #   Connections MUST use the Proxy Protocol (v1 or v2).
    #   The proxy can ialso Listen on ipv4 and ipv6.
    bind :::5000 accept-proxy
    bind *:5000 accept-proxy

    mode tcp
    # Detailed connection logging
    log global
    option tcplog

    # Only certain hosts (sending MTAs) can use this proxy, enforced via ACL
    acl valid_client_mta_hosts src 127.0.0.1 172.31.25.101
    tcp-request connection reject if !valid_client_mta_hosts
    use_backend out

frontend health_check
    mode http
    bind :::5001
    bind *:5001
    monitor-uri /haproxy_test
    log global # comment this out to omit healthchecks from the logs
```

however that seems to admit the possibility that 5001 might be up, but there's a problem with 5000.

Is there a way to enable monitoring directly of the `mode tcp` frontend with recent directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround:

Use a client that can add the proxy header, to ping the tcp front-end.

Make a request toward the proxy health service.
The source and dest of the request can be the "loopback" address.

```
 ./happie 35.90.110.253:5000 127.0.0.1:0 127.0.0.1:5001
Sending header version 2
00000000  0d 0a 0d 0a 00 0d 0a 51  55 49 54 0a 21 11 00 0c  |.......QUIT.!...|
00000010  7f 00 00 01 7f 00 00 01  00 00 13 89              |............|

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 58
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/html

<html><body><h1>200 OK</h1>
Service ready.
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [track](http://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#5.2-track) for health checks on different ports.

Example code

```
backend be_static
# more config options

server static_stor host:5000 track be_static_check_stor/static_check more_server_params

# check backend
backend be_static_check_stor
# more config options

server static_check host:5001 check more_server_params
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that applies to the back-end? .. I'm seeking a way for the front end to declare its availability.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your Statement "I'm seeking a way for the front end to declare its availability." A frontend routes traffic to backend which send the requests to the servers. Maybe you can add some more informations or a ascii art to the original request.

Comment: Or you can use a "listen" block instead of a frontend block http://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#4

Comment: Hopefully it's clear now .. this is about providing a way for the frontend (or listener) to show that it's up in TCP mode, (like monitor_uri does for HTTP mode).

The "listen" block seems useful. Can you write rules that will provide preset responses via TCP? e.g. just a simple string that says "220 OK" or similar.